# how to create simplest text link to open visitors email client in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, email, button

I would like to know the simplest way to use a text link and open a visitors email client.

Comment: flash...simplest way(no code): http://icetemplates.com/imageshelp/ques9-img2.jpg

Answer (score 1):

A simple example:

```
<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu">
```

You can read more [here](http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html).

Keep in mind that should you want to do anything more than your basic "Look ma! I sent a mail!", you should do it with forms and a proper server-side handler to send the mail for you. MailTo-links are inherently buggy and cumbersome. Especially if you should want to put anything besides regular ascii in the text, as email-clients handle charactersets differently.